# Automating the mathematical tool

Tags: vba, excel

I have developed a calculator in "TOOL.xlsx" file. It takes 4 inputs and returns 2 outputs. The calculation is performed on the calculator sheet in the "Tool.xlsx" workbook. 4 inputs correspond to 1 data set. I have another Excel file named "DATA.xlsx" that contains around 20,000 datasets (4 inputs per data set) and it also has an output column that collects the output. I would like to automate the "DATA.slsx" and "Tool.xlsx" interaction so that the inputs for the "TOOL.xlsx" are automatically called from the "data.xlsx" and the output column in the "data.xlsx" are filled with the outputs of "TOOL.xlsx". I would really appreciate any help because I am really stuck up here. PS: I an new to VBA.

#### screenshot that ilustrates my problem

[image: screenshot at this link]

Answer (score 0):

I would like to see the formula behind the input/output cells

and need to put those formula in second sheet.

to give a try, use

=SheetName!CellAddress in second sheet input/output cells

Comment: the formula used is a complex one. it contains lots of dependent and independent variables. So cant insert the formula. Calculation has to be done in a separate sheet as shown in pic

Comment: if u want i can send you the excel file itself

Comment: yes you can send me file on rajtrivedi2001 at gmail dot com